# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in autocomplete

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

I am new to json and jquery programming. I am trying a Google like search. And here is code:

**index.php**

```
 <script>
     $(function() {
            //autocomplete
        $("#tweety").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.get("source.json", {
                q: request.term
            }, function(data) {
                response($.map(data.tracks, function (el) {
                    return el.label, el.value;
                }));
            });
        },
        minLenght: 1
        }); 

    });

 <script>

 <input type="text" id="tweety">
```

My problem are is that the browser respond with this message in console "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined".

How can I able to solve that problem as well as show the dropdown output of autocomplete.

Comment: Autocomplete id name added incorrectly .its 'tweet' not 'tweety'

Comment: HI @LMK its a typo error only.thanks

Comment: I dont see where you are calling `length()` in your code! Could it be another script causing the error?